# Why my toolbar is overlapping my textView?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the `xml` layout of the file
Here, when i made the layout the `toolbar` is overlapping the content of my `textView`, Why this is happening.
Have tried several other things but no luck..!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="alpit isfdfsdfwefwes great jhfjhvjhhbnmbjk"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"

    >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my current situation.
[image: Why this is happening ?]

Comment: FYI : Remove `android:weightSum="1"` and set `android:textSize="20sp"` instead of `android:textSize="20dp"`

Comment: use fitSystemwindow = true

Comment: Done, but still no improvement .

Comment: @AlpitAnand check below answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is just because you have given padding to your Drawer layout and your relative layout start drawing from top which includes paddingTop also

please try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="alpit isfdfsdfwefwes great jhfjhvjhhbnmbjk"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"

        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

also you can use parent layout as relative layout and inside these use Drawer layout

Answer (score 2):

add top margin to relativelayout like

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:weightSum="1">
```

I should have written this as comment but I don't have reputations so I have added it as answer

Comment: Thanks, it surely worked but won't it be a bit hardcode.Android layout on diff phone size might get disoriented. Thank You...!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this give margin to **Textview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alpit.formula2.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text=" alpit isfdfsdfwefwes great jhfjhvjhhbnmbjk"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        ></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put hard coded values to layout you can try this,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="alpit isfdfsdfwefwes great jhfjhvjhhbnmbjk"
        android:textSize="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

and use into relative_layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```